# Replace Image SRC On CLick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a WooCommerce setup where I have a gallery. One is big image and others are thumbnails.

What I want to do is when someone clicks on the thumbnail, it replaces the big image and the big image comes there at the thumbnail. How do I do that? Any JavaScript guru here to help?

Here is the full HTML output.

```
<div class="images product-gallery ">
            <div class="big_image">
                <a title="" href="http://www.domain.com/image001.jpg" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom"><img width="300" height="300" alt="" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" src="http://www.domain.com/image001-300x300.jpg"></a>
            </div>

                <div class="thumbnails">
                    <a title="" class="zoom first" href="http://www.domain.com/image002.jpg"><img width="90" height="90" alt="" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://www.domain.com/image002-90x90.jpg"><div class="numbers">1</div></a>
                    <a title="" class="zoom" href="http://www.domain.com/image003.jpg"><img width="90" height="90" alt="" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://www.domain.com/image003-90x90.jpg"><div class="numbers">2</div></a>
                    <a title="" class="zoom last" href="http://www.domain.com/image004.jpg"><img width="90" height="90" alt="" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://www.domain.com/image004-90x90.jpg"><div class="numbers">3</div></a>
                    <a title="" class="zoom first" href="http://www.domain.com/image005.jpg"><img width="90" height="90" alt="" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="http://www.domain.com/image005-90x90.jpg"><div class="numbers">4</div></a>
                </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I don't need that `<a href="` part on image. So, you can ignore them.
I have very little knowledge in JavaScript, so please help me out. All I want is when someone click on any of the thumbnail image, the thumbnail image replaces the big image and the big image replace the clicked thumbnail. So basically the alter positions.

Please pardon me for my poor English.

Answer (score 2):

**Jquery**

You can use src `attr()` in `onclick` event

```
 $("#target").attr("src","newUrlOfTheImg");
```

or with plain **java script**

```
document.getElementById("target").src="newUrlOfTheImg";
```

[And have look once](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/jquery-change-image-src-attribute)

Comment: @Sergio OP tagged it with jQuery.

Comment: @Baadshah, I saw that :) you got +1

Comment: Thanks, but I'll need more elaboration. Not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("target").src="myNewImage.extension";`

Pure javascript alternative that you can use on the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.zoom').on('click', function() {
  $('.big_image').find('img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
 });
});
```

You should try this out, however it would be better to have separate thumbnail and big-images files for loading purposes.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten the final parenthesis, I have tested it and it functions. Don't forget that you will need a preventdefault or remove your href otherwise it will just link you to the next page.